# Access local storage variable in multipage HTML website

Tags: html, css, local-storage

I am creating a multipage website that uses javascript to, among other things, create and read the entry "darkTheme" in local storage if the user enables dark mode. It works flawlessly in (`index.html`), but when I navigate to another page on the website (e.g. `FAQ.html`), I am unable to access that variable (Firefox says there is "No data present for selected host") and the dark theme reverts to light, since no variable was created for it.

I don't want to have the user enable dark theme on every page individually. So how can I make it so that variable can be accessed across all other pages in my website instead of just the index?

This is the structure of the website so far:

```
.
├── img
│   ├── banner1.png
│   └── banner2.png
├── js
│   ├── FAQ.js
│   └── theme.js
├── html
│   └── FAQ.html
├── index.html
└── style.css
```

The Java script:

```
let darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');
const themeToggle = document.querySelector('#themeButton');
const bodyBackground = document.getElementById('#body');

const enableDark = () => {
    document.body.classList.add('darktheme');
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'enabled');
    themeToggle.innerHTML = `<i id="themeButton__icon" icon-name="sun"></i>`;
    lucide.createIcons();
};

const disableDark = () => {
    document.body.classList.remove('darktheme');
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', null);
    themeToggle.innerHTML = `<i id="themeButton__icon" icon-name="moon"></i>`;
    lucide.createIcons();
};

if (darkTheme === 'enabled') {
    document.body.classList.add('notransition');
    enableDark();
    document.body.classList.remove('notransition');
} else {
    disableDark();
}

themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');
    if (darkTheme !== 'enabled') {
        enableDark();
    } else {
        disableDark();
    }
});
```

If I inspect index.html with FF, under Storage > Local Storage I see that the variable is created. But if I do the inspection to FAQ.html, there isn't any variable there. I expected to be able to access the variable from the "parent" page in "child" page as well.

BTW, I am working on the project by opening the .html on my machine with a browser and making edits on a text editor. I haven't hosted it somewhere yet. I am assuming that this behaviour will continue once I host it, please let me know if this is *not* the case.

This is my first website, am I approaching this in a poor way?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your javascript that deals with `localstorage`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LeeTaylor just added it.

Comment: http:// www.example.com https:// www.example.com and https:// example.com are all different domains with different localStorage. Did the link to FAQ change which domain you are on?

Comment: @Wayne  I would not think so, but I would guess yes. I am opening the file on my computer with my browser. The `FAQ.html` file is a folder deeper (in the `html` folder as seen on the tree I posted) than the `index.html`. Maybe that counts as a different domain? If it is indeed the case, once I host the site will I have this same problem (I plan to upload that same file structure to github and host it there for starters) or is it just a temporary one bc it is a folder deeper and I am opening the file from my HD?

Comment: @greenmeridian you can also use the browser javascript console and type in localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'enabled'); and localStorage.getItem('darkTheme'); As long as you are on the same domain you will get back whatever you set. localStorage is the domain/subdomain not a directory level. That said www is a subdomain or different domain than the non-www of the same site. http:// 127.0.0.1 is different domain than http:// localhost and different than http:// 127.0.0.2